# Maintain scroll position and dynamically update the list of options

Tags: react-select

I want to dynamically update the list of options without forcing the dropdown to be in a loading state. I can get this to work, but the when the options are updated, the scroll position of the dropdown is reset to the default state (if it was open)

Is there a best practice for this use case?

My current thinking is that I should maintain the scroll position and refresh it once I update the list of options if the dropdown is open, but hoping there is a simpler solution.